# How do I create a URL from a form field?

Tags: forms, redirection

I am getting too much escaping. The url is created in a module that redirects the for result.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = url('studio/' . $studio_profile->field_studio_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']. '/class-timetable');
```

I am getting this

http://localhost.dev:8888/studio/John%2527s%2520LazyBoy%2520Tester/class-timetable

Not this

http://yogahive.dev:8888/studio/John%27s%20LazyBoy%20Tester/class-timetable

That is - the escapes look escaped in John's LazyBoy Tester.

How do I correctly redirect?

Comment: Are you attempting to redirect after node creation? It is not clear what you are attempting to do.

Comment: No - not a node creation. Submit form, does a credit transfer as the save action.

Comment: you need to urlencode the path yourself.